# enviar data desde el interceptor a un componente Angular

Tags: angular

necesito enviar un mensaje desde un interceptor donde manejo los mensajes HTTP a un componente, tengo un servicio donde por medio de sweetalert muestro los mensajes ya sean de erorres o no, pero no puedo implementarlo desde el interceptor para que si dentro un componente se desencadeno el error mostraselo al usuario:

```
export class ErrorInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor{
 
  constructor(private uimessage: UiMessagesService) { }
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log('pasooooo');
    
    return next.handle( req ).pipe(
      catchError( this.manejarError )
    );
    //throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
 
  manejarError( error: HttpErrorResponse ) {
    console.log('Sucedió un error');
    console.log('Registrado en el log file');
    console.warn(error);
    this.uimessage.getMiniInfrmativeMsg('test','error');
    return throwError('Error personalizado');
  }
}
```

**"uimessage"** es la variable que me conecta con el servicio, al invocarla sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera mostrar al usuario los mensajes ue asta ahora solo puedo poner en consola, gracias de antemano.

Comment: No veo en el código que hagas uso de ese uimessage, o que intentes acceder a getMiniInfortiveMsg, que es lo que da el error. ¿Estás seguro que ése es el código que se está ejecutando?

Comment: hice la correccion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece como si las dependencias del interceptor no estuvieran bien definidas en el archivo `app.module.ts`. Revisa que estén definidas tal y como se especifica en esta otra respuesta en stackoverflow.

```
   {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: ErrorInterceptorService,
        multi: true,
        deps: [LocalStorageService]
    },
```